# using the export button function to another php file

Tags: php

This is the form.php file and i would like to put export button file to another php file. I  am still rocky for php language.

### form php

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for("attendance/viewAttendanceRecord"); ?>" id="reportForm" method="post" name="frmAttendanceReport">
        <fieldset>
            <ol>
                <?php
                if ($form->hasErrors()) {
                    echo $form['employeeName']->renderError();
                }
                ?>
                <?php echo $form->render(); ?>
                <?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields(); ?>                

                <li class="required">
                    <em>*</em> <?php echo __(CommonMessages::REQUIRED_FIELD); ?>
                </li>
            </ol>
            <p class="formbuttons">
        <input type="button" class="" id="btExport" onclick='myfunction()' value="<?php echo __('Export') ?>"/>
```

I want to use export function in this action.php file

### action.php

```
if($post['export'] == '1')
{
  //statement
}
```

Comment: you mean `$_POST['btExport']` ? and you should add `name` attribute to button also.

Comment: you mean like this <input type="button" class="" id="btExport" onclick='myfunction()' name ='export' value="<?php echo __('Export') ?>"/>

Comment: yes that will also work since you're checking `$_POST['export']` in export.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php uses `name` attribute of the elements in order to build `$_POST` array. So add `name` attribute to button along with other input elements as follows.

```
<input type="submit" id="btExport" name="btExport" value="<?php echo __('Export') ?>"/>
```

in **action.php** do something like the following to handle posted values.

```
if($_POST["btExport"])
{
  //statement
}
```

or you can also check if `$_POST` is empty or not as follows

```
if (!empty($_POST))
{
  //statement
}
```

Comment: i try put statement in if($_POST["btExport"])                                        print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
print 'alert("success")'; 
      print '</script>'; but not working

Comment: you're using `name ='export'`. you should check `if($_POST["export"])`.

Comment: what do you see when you `print_r($_POST);` ?

Comment: when i click it nothing come out. @_@

Comment: ah my bad. use `<input type="submit">`, not `<input type="button">`